# Help in identifying a sci-fi movie about some mechanical beings traveling back in time to murder people

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, robots

I remember when I was much younger I watched a video with some odd robotic teenagers who travel back in time and meet the grim reaper (like from Scream) in hell or similar. I wish I could remember more details but I was too young.

Comment: Rondo might know...

Comment: How long ago was it?  Was this live action or animated?

Comment: From the title, I was thinking [Apex](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109144/), but the description doesn't match up

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137571/looking-for-80s-sci-fi-movie-aliens-who-fuse-robotic-band-members (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 20):

I'm pretty sure this is [*Bill and Ted's Bogus Journey* (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101452/). Bill and Ted are killed by their evil android doubles that have been sent back in time and have to fight the Grim Reaper to get out of Hell and return to the world of the living.

Comment: Also, this movie included two sets of robot Bill and Ted.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the one. Can you think of any other movies that might follow the same overall theme?

Comment: @carltalua - I would be very surprised if this was incorrect.  My immediate reaction to this was Bogus Journey.

Comment: That's a pretty narrow theme... Does "How's it Hanging Death", "Exceeeellent", and Death playing Battleship/Twister against the teens ring any bells?