# Looking for 80s sci-fi movie, Aliens who fuse, Robotic Band Members

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

So im looking for a movie I think is from the 80s (maybe 90s) involving two aliens and a robot band (I think).

I remember seeing this movie as a kid during the 90s. The only thing I can remember where to alien creatures riding in a shopping cart in a mall. Outside of the mall the two alien creatures "collided" and fused with each other. And also there was a robot band (I think). I am sorry if this sounds kind of "druggy" or whatever but I have a very clear memory of this particular scene/scenes. I also remember the alien creatures looking somewhat like E.T (short, brownish).

Please tell me that this is not some kind of fever dream I had as a kid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like [Bill and Ted's Bogus Journey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_%26_Ted's_Bogus_Journey).

The plot involved four robot copies of the title characters (who themselves were time travelling musicians and star of the previous movie, Bill And Ted's Excellent Adventure).  Towards the end, two of them (the ones that looked more robotic) joined the band.

[image]

The aliens were called "Station", an alien genius they met in Heaven (after they were killed by their evil robot duplicates), who built the Good-Robot-Bill-and-Ted and they fused together into one larger alien who also could only say "Station".

[image]

The Grim Reaper, Death himself, also joined the band.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! i thought I had lost my mind!

Comment: @Octoboy Rather than being at a mall, they were in the parking lot of an electronics store. They had just bought materials to build the robots, which Station proceeded to do (in the back of a van, on the way to the concert) after fusing in the parking lot. Watch both movies. They are righteous.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I sure will! (: